# Property 'XXX' is missing in type 'YYY' but required in type 'ZZZ'

Tags: typescript

I'm having trouble initializing class properties.
I have typescript code like this.

```
export class myClass  {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  public getCopy(anotherClass: myClass): myClass {
    return {
      a: anotherClass.a,
      b: anotherClass.b
    };
  }
}
```

But I'm getting this error message.

> Property 'getCopy' is missing in type '{ a: number; b: number; }' but
> required in type 'myClass'

Why is it thinking getCopy() is a property?
I have C# background and C# does not require to initialize functions.
Is there a way to create a class instance and initialize properties without initializing functions?
I'm looking for an easier way like C# code below.

```
var newInstance = new myClass()
{
  a = 1,
  b = 2
};
```

Instead of doing like this.

```
var newInstance = new myClass();
newInstance.a = 1;
newInstance.b = 2;
```

Or is this not possible with typescript?

Comment: You're just returning a vanilla object, *not* an instance of myClass. *"Is there a way to create a class instance"* - `new`.

Comment: You are returning the datastructure { a, b } and not a class of type `myClass` (what you specify as return type)

Comment: OK. So, I can do something like this right? but does typescript have some simpler ways to initialize properties?
export class myClass  {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  public getCopy(anotherClass: myClass): myClass {
    let newClass = new myClass();
    newClass.a = anotherClass.a;
    newClass.b = anotherClass.b;
    return newClass;
  }
}

Comment: I don't really see why you want to do something in the same way like another language does it. The question is a bit, what do you actually need. In typescript, you don't really need a class, you must just match the properties based on the definition, so you can have an interface defining your `myClass` and just use the object literal filling the required properties

Comment: It is because I'm new to typescript and I don't know what is possible and what is not possible with typescript. So, I'm trying to learn this new language by comparing with the language I'm familiar with. I understand it is possible without using a class, but I'm trying to explore the options what typescript can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new clone instance of myClass class:

```
public getCopy(anotherClass: myClass): myClass {    
  return Object.assign(new myClass(), {...});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getCopy` *is* a property of myClass. You are declaring it as a property of myClass. An instance of `myClass` could also be written using Object notation:

```
const myClassInstance = {
  a,
  b,
  getCopy,
}
```

Since `getCopy` is not optional on `myClass`, you must have this property and it must match the type of the `myClass` delcaration, so it must be a function.

---

All that being said, it's not entirely clear to me why you need an instance method that creates a copy of the class. You could just have this as a standalone function instead. Cloning the top level of an object can also be done in a few different ways including the spread operator, so you generally don't need to write your own function to do this either.

```
const myClass = new myClass();
myClass.a = 1
myClass.b = 2;
const myClassCopy = { ...myClass };
```

Comment: Basically, I'm looking for an easier way to create a class instance and initialize class properties like how C# can do.

Comment: You could set the properties via a constructor, or you can create a standalone function (not part of a class) that takes the parameters and creates it. I'm not familiar with C#, so I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but C# has heavily influenced TypeScript, so you can probably do something that is fairly identical.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think you need a class for the code you provided, just describe your datastructure in an interface, say

```
interface DataStructure {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}
```

and then create an object which has these properties, say:

```
const instance: DataStructure = { a: 5, b: 'test' };
```

You can then use the interface as well as parameters for your functions or return values. It doesn't have to be a class, so for example:

```
function someFunction( b: DataStructure): void {
}

someFunction(instance); // works
someFunction({a: 10, b: 'test'}); // works
someFunction({a: 10}); // doesn't work, b is required
```